# React fetch Firebase get unique key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

does anyone know how to get unique key value from firebase database? i want to store it inside state and print it into console.log.

this is example of unique key
[image]

this is the code, i just want to show it in console

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      newId: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://redditclone-project.firebaseio.com/data.json", {
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    console.log('value key, ex:-LzpvyLJnKgDllnTE-eW');
  }
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

[image]

thanks

edit : inside res
and added my firebase link

Comment: What output do you get from `console.log(res);`?

Comment: I also noticed there is no `linkfirebase.json` in the JSON screenshot that you shared.

Comment: edited, also plus console.log(res)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to print the keys from the JSON, you can use `Object.keys()`:

```
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  console.log(Object.keys(res));
});
```

Since `Object.keys()` returns an array, you can then also use for example `Array.forEach()` to loop over these keys.